# Decimal clipped by concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I need to concatenate two decimal values like:

```
select 0.1 || ' - ' || 0.5 from dual
```

And get a result as "0.1 - 0.5", but I get ".1 - .5".

I tried `to_char` and `cast` functions but I get the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_char()` function with appropriate format model. Here is an example:

```
select to_char(0.1, 'fm0D9') || ' - ' || 
       to_char(0.5, 'fm0D9') as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES     
---------
0.1 - 0.5
```

Where `D` is decimal separator, period(`.`) in this case, and `fm` format model modifier - removes leading and trailing blanks.

**[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31814)**